# XGBoost with catigorical (nominal) features

Tags: machine-learning, python, categorical-data, boosting

I have several numeric features and two catigorical features. The catigorical features have no order (nominal), they are for example `colors`; red, blue, yellow, green... and `place of birth`; USA, Spain, Germany. The target feature is binary catigorical which can be easily converted to numeric with 1 and 0.

How can XGBoost handle those catigorical features? should I switch from catigorical to numeric?

If so, how? I mean, can red, blue, yellow.. become 1, 2, 3 ? will that affect the information provided by that feature column in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, XGBoost handles categorical features *nowadays* (from ver. 1.5.x onwards).

The functionality is currenty experimental but as it stands XGBoost handles categorical features the same way that LightGBM does; in short, the categories are binned and then sorted according to the training objective at each split. Effectively that is a one-dimensional clustering and allows us to find the optimal split of this "binned" variable fast and efficiently. A worked example can be found under the [Categorical Data](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html) tutorial in the XGBoost homepage.

As final comment: when using categorical features with relatively low cardinality (e.g. <10 categories) all implementations are pretty interchangeable; differences start materialising when we have higher cardinality features. Similarly, for *very* high cardinality features (1000+) like textual descriptions, embedding the categories in a low-dimensional *numeric* space might be simpler and easier to work with.